# How does this Java code work?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int [][]shatner = new int[1][1];
    int []rat = new int[4];
    shatner[0] = rat;
    System.out.println(shatner[0][3]);
}
```

surprised, The output is 0, why Java doesn't check this kind of indexOutOfBound error?

Comment: So, you posted an answer with absolutely no question? On StackOverflow, typically the questions come first.

Comment: I think the question is assumed - "why is it so?"

Comment: This is a perfectly legitimate question.

Comment: It can be read as a question - "Why isn't an IndexOutOfBoundsException thrown by this code?"

Comment: don't make the mistake of thinking java arrays of arrays are loke fortean 2d arrays.

Comment: Damn Palm Pre keyboard.  I meant to say "are like fortran 2d arrays".

Comment: If it was a fortean array, you'd access `shatner[0]` and get a rain of frogs... or rats... or something.

Comment: People are way too synical on this site sometimes.  @Justin its a fine question.

Comment: @John W. - Now that the question has been revised four times, I'd agree. The original wording gave the post a completely different meaning.

Comment: @Justin fair enough, the changing of the question could make it look like your comment were directed to what is currently posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't be surprised. shatner[0] is an array (rat) and happens to be of length 4. So shartner[0][3] is rat[3] which happens to be 0..

Comment: hi nc3b:
so shatner[0] can be assigned to any size of int array?
and what does int[1][1] mean? one array of int[1]?

Comment: @chun - the int[1][1] declaration sets up the initial dimensions of the array, which is basically an array of a single array containing a single element.  The assignment changes it to an array of a single array containing 4 elements.  In Java, multi-dimensional arrays can have variable lengths for each row.

Answer (score 5):

Where do you see an "indexOutOfBound error"? The code does the following:

- Initalize an array (size 1) of `int` arrays (size 1), i.e. a 2D array, contents are intialized with 0
- Initalize a array of `int`, size 4, content is intialized with 0
- set the single element of the 2D array to the size 4 1D array
- access the last element of the first array in the 2D array, which is 0

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing going out of bounds.

The 0th row in the `shatner` array  gets reinitialized to `int[4]`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no index out of bounds error. shatner is an array of arrays. You replaced the first array of length one with a new one of length four. So now shatner[0][3] is a perfectly legit place in memory.

Answer (score 3):

It's not that Java doesn't check the IndexOutOfBoundsException.  It's that the answer SHOULD be zero.  The key line is

```
shatner[0] = rat;
```

Since that means that the 0th index of `shatner` is pointing to an array of length 4, `shatner[0][4]` is totally valid.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking it's because java's arrays are working a bit differently than expected.  You initialize `shatner` to [1][1], meaning something like, `{{0},{0}}` in memory.

However, you then assign an integer to the first element, turning it into `{{0,0,0,0},{0}}` in memory, so Java is addressing the newly assigned index.

Comment: Actually in memory you have an array of references that point to int arrays. In memory the cluster of arrays need not, and most likely will not, be next to each other. Especially after he reassigned the first one to rat.

Comment: what does int[1][1] mean ? one array of int[ANYSIZE] ?

Answer (score 0):

Arrays need not be rectangular in Java. This is a jagged array and is perfectly fine.

Comment: I think to be jagged, first shatner would have to have 2 rows, and they would be unequal lengths.  This variable has only 1 row.

Comment: It's still technically a jagged array, even if it doesn't look like one when drawn out.